Difference in My perceptron and sklearn Perceptron
I coded the perceptron algorithm form scratch and compared the weights I obtained after training with the weights I obtained after training the sklearn perceptron model. I believe even the sklearn model initializes the weights and biases as a zero vector and I chose the learning rate eta0=1 to match my perceptron code. (Note: the bias in my code is the last term in the vector w_b)
My Code:
def perceptron(X_train, y_train):
    #initialize weights as 0
    w = np.zeros(len(X_train.columns))
    b = 0
    w_b = np.append(w, b)
    while True:
        misclassifications = 0  
        for X , Y in zip(X_train.values, y_train.values):
            X_i = np.append(X, 1)
            if Y*(np.dot(X_i,w_b)) <= 0:
                w_b = w_b + Y*X_i
                misclassifications += 1
        if misclassifications == 0:
            break
    return w_b

w_b = perceptron(X_train, y_train)

Result: [-3.   6.7 -1. ]
sklearn code:
perceptron = Perceptron(max_iter=1000, eta0=1,random_state=42) 
perceptron.fit(X_train, y_train)

print("weights are",perceptron.coef_)
print("bias is",perceptron.intercept_)

Result: weights are [[-4.7 10.1]] bias is [-2.]
I expected the weights to be same but they aren't. Any clue on why?


Using "random_state" means something random is happening. Unlike your custom implementation, sklearn shuffles your training data by default.
Convergence: You set "max_iter" to 1000 so the weights get adjusted 1000 times. But your custom implementation will stop adjusting the weights as soon as there are no misclassifications.
Your actual data. Does it really have a linear relationship? This would matter as well.
Did you use exactly the same train and test data ?

